# Excel, Remove Duplicates by Moving Unique Values to Another sheet

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

I have an Excel Sheet with about 150000 rows. In the below given format.

```
|--------------------------------|
|          First Sheet           |
|--------------------------------|
|column1  | column2  | column3   |
|---------|----------|-----------|
|code1    | state1   | district1 |
|code2    | state1   | district1 |
|code3    | state1   | district2 |
|code4    | state2   | district3 |
|--------------------------------|
```

There are duplicates in the columns. I'd like to get all the Distinct or Unique volumn values on to another sheet as such

```
|-------------|    |-----------------|
|    State    |    |     District    |
|-------------|    |-----------------|
| id | value  |    | id  | value     |
|-------------|    |-----------------|
| 1  | state1 |    | 1   | district1 |
| 2  | state2 |    | 2   | district2 |
|-------------|    | 3   | district3 |
                   |-----------------|
```

and then update the First sheet to

```
|--------------------------------|
|          First Sheet           |
|--------------------------------|
|column1  | column2  | column3   |
|---------|----------|-----------|
|code1    | 1        | 1         |
|code2    | 1        | 1         |
|code3    | 1        | 2         |
|code4    | 2        | 3         |
|--------------------------------|
```

Please let me know if I can do this using **Formulas** in Excel.

My main reason to do this is so that I can manipulate the data to match how my tables will finally be and then export the data to MySQL.

Is my approach right or am I just complicating things?

Comment: There's not really enough information to say for sure, but on the face of it, I'd say that you're just complicating things.

Comment: are you trying to normalize the tables? i guess it's one time job? if yes just copy the sheet > use the "remove duplicates" function in Excel for each column > assign them id > do a vlookup to replace ID in the first sheet > import the sheet as csv into mysql?

Comment: @Strawberry: I'd like to know a better way to do the same thing. One way I found was to export the Excel as CSV to MySQL and then write queries to manipulate the table. But there are like 10 columns and I'll have to write 20 SQL statements minimum to get this done..

Comment: @krishKM: Yup, I think that is what I'm looking for. I'll try it out and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are the steps to achieve what you have said in your question:

Step 1) Select *Column2* from *Sheet1*, Goto **DATA** tab > click **Advance Filter**. Using Advance filter, you can get list of *unique records* to *Sheet2* under column named as *StateName*. You can specify the location for unique records. And, dont forget to check **Unique Records Only** checkbox. Check the attached image:

[image: To use Advance Filter]

Step 2) Once you finished step 1 for both State and District column. You can number the IDs like StateID and District IDs in sheet2.

Step 3) Now, you need to do **VLOOKUP** for *StateNames* and *Districtnames* from Sheet2 to get respective *StateID* and *DistrictID*. You can get result in Column D and E.

Step 4) Finally, you just need to copy column D and E and do paste special in column B.